# Evaluate Distribution

Tags: probability

Evaluate the distributions $p(a), p(b|c)$ and $p(c|a)$ corresponding to the joint distribution given in Table 8.2. Hence show by direct evaluation that $p(a, b, c) = p(a)p(c|a)p(b|c)$.

[Table 8.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51CHS.png)

```
a   b   c   p(a, b, c)
0   0   0   0.192
0   0   1   0.144
0   1   0   0.048
0   1   1   0.216
1   0   0   0.192
1   0   1   0.064
1   1   0   0.048
1   1   1   0.096
```

Not sure where to start with this problem. First I thought I would setup inequalities using the table but without knowing if $a,b,c$ are independent of each other or not. But that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well   $~p(a) = \sum_b\sum_c p(a,b,c)\\\qquad = p(a,0,0)+p(a,0,1)+p(a,1,0)+p(a,1,1)$

So the marginal distribution of $a$ (without doing any addition)
$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}\hline a & p(a)
\\ \hline 0   &   0.192+0.144+ 0.048+0.216
\\ \hdashline 1   &   0.192+0.064+ 0.048+ 0.096
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Next: $p(b\mid a) = \sum_c p(a,b,c)/p(a)$

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|}\hline a & b & p(b\mid a)
\\ \hline 0 & 0  & \frac{ 0.192+0.144}{ 0.192+0.144+ 0.048+0.216
}
\\ \hdashline 0 & 1 &  
\\ \hdashline 1 & 0 &  
\\ \hdashline 1 & 1 &  
\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Can you do the rest?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

$P(a, b, c) = P(a)P(c|a)P(b|c)$

Use the definition for conditional probability.

$$P(U=u \mid V=v) = \frac{P(U=u \cap V=v)}{P(V=v)}$$

$$P(a, b, c) = P(a)\frac{P(c \cap a)}{P(a)}\frac{P(b \cap c)}{P(c)}$$

for the case $a=1, \: b=1, \: c=1$

LHS: $P(a=1, b=1, c=1)= 0.096$

RHS: $$=P(a=1)\frac{P(c=1 \cap a=1)}{P(a=1)}\frac{P(b=1 \cap c=1)}{P(c=1)}=0.096$$